Prevent scroll to top when child dialog closes in parent dialog | Primeng Dialog service
I have nested dialogs using primeng dialog service, I set focusOnShow false. When I closes dialog B inside dialog A, dialog A's component scrolled to top and first focusable element receives focus. How to prevent it.
Dialog Config
private defaultOverlayConfig:DynamicDialogConfig = {
    data:{},
    showHeader:false,
    closable:false,
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%',
    focusOnShow:false,
    focusTrap:false,
    style: { height:'100%', 'max-height':'100%', 'border-radius':'0', 'box-shadow':'none'},
    contentStyle:{height:'100%', padding:'0px', margin:'0px', 'border-radius':'0'},
    maskStyleClass:'overlay-mask-style',
    appendTo:document.getElementById('overlay'),
    transitionOptions: '0ms linear'
   }

When dialog B closes I want dialog A scroll position as it was before.

I added pButton to first button in the component inside dialog A(parent dialog) and this behavior stopped.
<p-button pButton class="back-button" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" (onClick)="goBack()"/>

I've also faced this issue and resolved it by setting focusOnClose: false for dialog B.
